Why aren't a number series' average in multiple steps equal to the average in a single step?
Say we hv a series of n numbers.
Case 1:
We take avg of first two numbers, then take avg of this avg and the third number, then avg of this avg and the fourth number and so on, till the last number. We obtain a final average
Case 2: We take the avg of all n numbers together. We hv a final average
Why aren't avg1 and avg2 equal? Intuitively avg of two numbers shd be able to represent them both equally while taking average with another number, but the result is different for the average of all numbers together. Both lead to a central tendency, yet aren't the same.
Avg1(2,3,4)= 3.25
Avg2(2,3,4)= 3
Mathematically it looks like the effect of the denominator change. But wht is the intuitive reason behind this anyways?

The third number comes in at full strength while the others get diluted.  Say the three numbers were $A,B,C$.  Then your first average is $\frac 12\times \left(\frac {A+B}2+C\right)=\frac A4+\frac B4+\frac C2$ so $C$ contributes twice what the others contribute.

For case 1:
$$ \frac{2+3}{2} = 2.5$$
$$ \frac{2.5+4}{2} = 3.25$$
Which can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{\frac{2+3}{2}+4}{2} = 3.25$$
$$\frac{\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{2}+4}{2} = 3.25$$
$$\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{4} + \frac{4}{2} = 3.25$$
As you can see, not all the numbers are given equal weights, like for case 2:
$$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{3} + \frac{4}{3}$$
If we have 2 groups of apples, one group of 2, another group of 4, the average is 3. If we take a group of 3 apples (which represents the average), and add another group of 4 apples to it, now we have 3 groups, a group of 2 apples, a group of 4 apples and another group of 4 apples.
The group of 2 and 4 are represented by the group of 3 apples. If we want to take the average of all 3 groups using just 2 groups (the group representing the average, and the new group of 4 apples), which of these groups should have/holds more weight towards the average?
Obviously the group of apples which represents the average, because its actually made of 2 previous groups. So you cannot actually divide the group of 3 and 4 apples using the same number, because assigning different weights would be unfair.
